# Why doesn't the audio change when i re-click the button?

Tags: javascript, html

So basically im making a website
And i made it play a music when it clicks on a button
And i also want to make that when we re-click the button, it skips the song
But everytime i tried, it didn't work
I tried to make it change the outerHTML to change the onclick
And i also tried the .onclick = "" method
But nothing works, did i do something wrong?
Here's the code:

```
            var musicpaths = ['assets/music/Dunderpatrullen%20-%20To%20The%20Moon.mp3', 'assets/music/Big Giant Circles - Go For Distance.mp3',"assets/music/Bag Raiders - Shooting Stars.mp3","assets/music/NOMA - Brain Power.mp3","assets/music/Hans Zimmer - Time (Aviators Remix).mp3","assets/music/Danny Baranowsky - Moonsong.mp3"];
            var musicrandomizer = Math.round(Math.random(0, musicpaths.length - 1));
            var audio = new Audio("https://takeb1nzyto.space/" + musicpaths[musicrandomizer]);
            var firsttime = false;
            function changebuttononclick() {
                const onclickthing = "audio.innerHTML = ''; playrandomaudio;";
                document.getElementById("startmusicbutton").innerText = "skip music";
                document.getElementById("startmusicbutton").onclick = onclickthing;
                console.log("[Music Button]: Succesfully changed the button script & the button text!");
            };
            function playrandomaudio() {
                musicrandomizer = Math.round(Math.random(0, musicpaths.length - 1));
                audio = new Audio("https://takeb1nzyto.space/" + musicpaths[musicrandomizer]);
                audio.load();
                console.log("[Player]: Succesfully created a new audio element!");
                audio.play();
                console.log("[Player]: Succesfully played the song!");
                if (firsttime == false){
                    changebuttononclick();
                };
                firsttime = true;
                audio.onended = playrandomaudio; audio.innerHTML = "";
            };
            document.getElementById('startmusicbutton').onclick = playrandomaudio;
```

Comment: So from what I understand, if you click the button again it forwards to the next song?

Comment: no it picks a new random song

Comment: you are setting the innerHTML of the audio element to an empty string

Comment: i know that i changed it to an empty string

Comment: also you are assigning a string to the `onclick` property instead of a function

Comment: yeah but it still works if i try to click it for some reason

Comment: you should set it to a function. So the correct code should be:
`document.getElementById("startmusicbutton").onclick = playrandomaudio;`

also you can remove `audio.innerHTML = "";`

Another potential issue `changebuttononclick()` is never called

You can call this function after the first song is played, like this:

`audio.onended = function() { audio.innerHTML = ""; changebuttononclick(); };`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Math.random()` does not take arguments so you should get rid of that, I switched up `Math.round()` to `Math.floor()` so it rounds up the value to a valid index of the music array.

Then I also did some minor code cleanup to make the code more readable.

```js
var musicpaths = [
  'assets/music/Dunderpatrullen%20-%20To%20The%20Moon.mp3',
  'assets/music/Big Giant Circles - Go For Distance.mp3',
  'assets/music/Bag Raiders - Shooting Stars.mp3',
  'assets/music/NOMA - Brain Power.mp3',
  'assets/music/Hans Zimmer - Time (Aviators Remix).mp3',
  'assets/music/Danny Baranowsky - Moonsong.mp3'
];


var musicrandomizer = Math.floor(Math.random() * musicpaths.length);
var audio = new Audio("https://takeb1nzyto.space/" + musicpaths[musicrandomizer]);
var firsttime = true;
var musicButton = document.getElementById("startmusicbutton");

/**
 * Here i change the button on click if the user is listening for
 * the first time if not it will be play random music
 */
function changebuttononclick() {
  if (firsttime) {
    musicButton.innerText = "skip music";
    musicButton.onclick = skipmusic;
  } else {
    musicButton.innerText = "playrandommusic";
    musicButton.onclick = playrandomaudio;
  }
  console.log("[Music Button]: Successfully changed the button script & the button text!");
}

/** Basically your function
 * but slightly refactored to be more readable.
 */
function playrandomaudio() {
  if (audio) {
    audio.pause();
    audio = null; // delete the previously playing song to keep performance up
  }

  musicrandomizer = Math.floor(Math.random() * musicpaths.length);
  audio = new Audio("https://takeb1nzyto.space/" + musicpaths[musicrandomizer]);
  audio.load();
  console.log("[Player]: Successfully created a new audio element!");
  audio.play();
  console.log("[Player]: Successfully played the song!");
  audio.onended = changebuttononclick;
  firsttime = true;
}


/**
 * To skip the music we basically pause the audio and put the audio back to start.
 */
function skipmusic() {
  audio.pause();
  audio.currentTime = 0;
  changebuttononclick();
}

document.getElementById('startmusicbutton').onclick = playrandomaudio;
```

```html
<button id="startmusicbutton">Start Music Button</button>
```

Let me know if this helped, I'm happy to help you with further questions if needed.

Comment: I just updated the answer with a code snipet, I forgot to turn off the previously playing music. Try this new solution :)

Comment: it worked now! thanks for helping me!

Comment: No problem, please make sure to mark this answer as the solution, and goodluck with your project :)